# A free module over $\Bbb C[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, independence, free-modules

Define the square matrix $A$ over $\Bbb C[x]$ by
$$
A:=
\begin{pmatrix}
x & -2x \\
-x^{2} & x^{3}-x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

> Prove that the submodule $AV=\{ Av \mid v \in V \}$ 
>   of the $\Bbb C[x]$-module 
>   $V= \left\{ 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> f_{1} \\ f_{2}
> \end{pmatrix}
> \ \middle|\  f_{1},f_{2} \in \Bbb C[x]
> \right\}$ 
>   is a free module over $\Bbb C[x]$
>   and compute a basis for it.

I have worked on it as follows:
$$A\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ -x^2
\end{pmatrix}=:v_1, \quad A\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-2x \\ x^{3}-x
\end{pmatrix}:=v_2, \quad A\begin{pmatrix}
f_1 \\ f_2
\end{pmatrix}=f_1v_1+f_2v_2,$$
thus $v_1,v_2 \in AV$ and $v_1,v_2$ span $AV$. Therefore, $AV$ is a free module over $\Bbb C[x]$
once we prove $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb C[x]$.
Now assume $f_1v_1+f_2v_2=0$ for some $f_1,f_2 \in\Bbb C[x]$.
This gives a system of equations: $x(f_1-2f_2)=0$ and $-x^2f_1+(x^3-x)f_2=0$ for every $x$.
Solving this system gives: $f_1=f_2=0$.

Are we done? I am not sure whether I understand the action of $\Bbb C[x]$ on $V$ correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning is right. The only thing you need to know about $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is that it is a domain in order to conclude that $f_1=2f_2$ and  subsequently that $f_1=f_2=0$. There is not really an action of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ on $V$ given. But you could ask yourself for example if $A$ is an automorphism. But this is (almost) completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @MaikPickl Thanks for putting a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A\in M_n(R)$. Consider the submodule $M$ of $R^n$ given by $\{Av:v\in R^n\}$. This is nothing but the submodule of $R^n$ generated by the columns of $A$.
Obviously, if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent over $R$ then $M$ is free.
Moreover, whenever $R$ is a PID (as it is $\mathbb C[x]$) we have that $M$ is free, and one can find a basis by using the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $A$.

Comment: I'm glad to know a more general problem. Is it always true that $M$ is free with a basis containing columns of the Smith Normal Form of $A$?

Comment: @user In fact, the basis given by the SNF of $A$ does not necessarily consist from the columns of $A$. The SNF of $A$ provides the *invariant factors* of the submodule generated by the columns of $A$. (All I said holds for PIDs.)

Comment: I got it. Thanks!